# create spring bean List initializing by the method

Tags: java, spring

I have the method:

```
public List<IEntity> wordsCollection()
```

I need to create the bean with that list. This method ask DB for data and  gets it out. When I used method call - I do call several times. But I need the bean with that value.
How can I do this?

I need something like this:

```
<util:list id ="wc">
   value = collections.wordsCollection
</util:list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@PostConstruct` to load the data in your spring bean

The [PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.

```
public class SomeService{

  @PostConstruct
  public void loadCollection() throws Exception {
      wordsCollection();   
 }
}
```

Inject your dao in the spring bean and call the required method in the postconstruct method.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the retrived list in the session and reuse it among spring controllers when required. Otherwise you can use Spring's expression language(SpEL).